# Setting account in Android emulator which is behind proxy

Tags: android, networking, proxy, firewall

I want to setup a google account in android emulator but I am behind a corporate  firewall.

Whenever firewall is removed, i can setup the account but as i am behind the firewall i cannot always remove it. Is there any specific IP address that will redirects when I click account setup button? Is that IP static or dynamic?

Comment: is this off the topic??? if so, let me know where should i post to get the correct answer